# How to set configuration convention of matching property name is a string collection?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have two models:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NetId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Departments { get; set; }
    public string Titles { get; set; }
}


public class UserReport : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NetId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<string> Departments { get; set; }
    public List<string> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

And as such I can write my automapper mapping like this:

```
CreateMap<UserReport, UserModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Departments, x => x.MapFrom(y => string.Join("\n", y.Departments)))
            .ForMember(x => x.Titles, x => x.MapFrom(y => string.Join("\n", y.Titles)));
```

However, I don't want to do this for every instance of this, because this approach is going to be used on pretty much every POCO to DTO conversion. Is there a way I can write a convention in the config to check if the destination property name is of type string and it matches a property on the source type of `list<string>` to do the string join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings can nest so you just define an additional map for `List<string>` to `string`:

```
CreateMap<List<string>, string>().ConvertUsing(strings => {
    if (strings != null)
      return string.Join("\n", strings);
    return "";
});
```

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know that. So I assume then this map has to appear before any other 'higher-level' maps?

Comment: I don't believe the ordering of the mapping declarations will matter